# How to design architecture for LSTM neural network

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

Is there some guideline to designing architecture for neural networks?

I want to use LSTM network for predicting in time series. I have a small dictionary variation (8 values) but lot of their combinations.

How do I know how many memory block assemblies, how many memory cells each, input gates, forget gates, output gates and so on?

I am totally newbie, never used LSTM. I am in the very first phase - only research so far.

Comment: It depends on what kind of timeseries you're working with, and what the pattern length is between different outcomes. But I don't get what you are predicting, what do you mean with "I have a small dictionary variation"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are no solid guidelines for RNNs that would work every time. Try different combinations and see what works the best after a couple epochs and then train it more. Most often it depends on the pattern so it is mostly impossible to get the right network right away